# Do wildcards work in Assignment Rules?

Tags: leads, assignment-rules

Working on Lead Assignments but there are several counties that may be spelled differently, even if correctly. I am wondering if wildcards ('*') work? For example, if a Lead's Country field is "Antigua & Barbuda" but someone spells it with "and" instead of an ampersand, couldn't I just put a wildcard in there? Will it ignore the rule altogether and just look for a literal asterisk? I have a few instances where this would be helpful for me.